# LDA analysis error: object not found

Tags: r, debugging, data-mining, lda

I am trying to make a LDA analysis in R to some data. The code is below:

The data is defines as follows:

```
mydata=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), ncol=5, dimnames=list(c("ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4","ex5","ex6"),c("class","a","b","c","d")))
```

This is the result for "mydata":

```
class  a  b  c  d 
ex1     1  7 13 19 25 
ex2     2  8 14 20 26 
ex3     3  9 15 21 27 
ex4     4 10 16 22 28 
ex5     5 11 17 23 29 
ex6     6 12 18 24 30
```

Now, I try to make a LDA analysis using this code:

```
mydata.lda<-lda(class ~ mydata.a + mydata.b + mydata.c + mydata.d)
```

This is the error code I get:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'mydata.a' not found
Calls: lda ... eval -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
```

Why it is not working? Should I change something?

Comment: All of your predictors are (maximally) collinear, so an LDA makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mydata$a, not mydata.a. You could also just do (untested)

```
mydata.lda <- lda(class~a+b+c+d, data = mydata)
```

Comment: Thanks. But, I get another error: Error in model.frame.default(formula=class~a+b+c+d, data = mydata) : 'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

Comment: convert your matrix to a dataframe using as.data.frame

Comment: The same error message as before? It's also probably safer to define mydata as a dataframe in the first place, instead of defining as a matrix

Comment: Error: variables 1 2 3 4 appear to be constant within groups

Comment: That is an error in your data, can't help there. The variance within your variables is too small to perform LDA

Comment: I change to this: mydata=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,74,8,9,160,11,12,313,14,415,616,17,218,19,205,21,22,253,24,25,2262,27,228,249,530), ncol=5, dimnames=list(c("ex1","ex2","ex3","ex4","ex5","ex6"),c("class","a","b","c","d"))). I still got the same error "variables 1 2 3 4 appear to be constant within groups". Is the error in the numbers or in the code?

Comment: @RobJr You can't use an LDA with collinear predictors. One usually removes any collinear predictors from the data. In your case, *all* of your predictors `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` are collinear. Hence the error message. It might be a good idea to read up on the fundamental concepts of an LDA to understand why.